# UUID Field in django behave weired at mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, uuid

I have a Django model which looks like following

```
class CdrByBusinessFlowID(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        cc_id = models.IntegerField()
        business_flow_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I have created a model model with api response following

```
{
  "status": "pending",
  "business_flow_id": "13630f30-bfed-4e8d-bdbd-263d0da75175",
  "id": "3c337f4c-3236-4117-b519-c57fbcc001f8",
  "cc_id": "1610"
}
```

But unfortunately this id doesn't exist in database.

The value just modified to some other value like `1f604e31a4054d1e998b97433cc661a5`.

Thanks

Comment: I tried what you said but I am getting exact same value as i entered. Check this :  http://pastebin.com/AJvVVVyN You can try something like this in your shell terminal

Comment: I am using 1.10.2 Django version and MySQL version is  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Win64 (x86_64).

Comment: Can you try with sqlite3 default db and check if this is db issue?

Comment: Also note the comment related to postgres here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: tried with SQLite seems working perfectly...Django foks need eye on this..Thanks for help :)